# Adding UISwitch to MFMailComposeViewController

Tags: ios, mfmailcomposeviewcontroller

i have added in a UISwtich and now I'm wondering how i would add the state into a email for example if it is on i want it to say "on" in the email. Currently i have this.

```
- (IBAction)sendtoStudentathome:(id)sender {
MFMailComposeViewController *mailContoller = [[MFMailComposeViewController alloc]init];
[mailContoller setMailComposeDelegate:self];
NSString *email = @"admin@blah.co.uk";
NSArray *emailArray = [[NSArray alloc]initWithObjects:email, nil];
NSString *message = [@[_NameofResident.text, _NameofStudent.text, _AppointmentTime.date,     _NextAppointmentTime.date, _Confirmed.text, myswitch]componentsJoinedByString: @"\n"];
[mailContoller setMessageBody:message isHTML:NO];
[mailContoller setToRecipients:emailArray];
[mailContoller setSubject:@"Feedback"];
[self presentViewController:mailContoller animated:YES completion:nil];
}

-(void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
[[self NameofResident] resignFirstResponder];
}

-(void)mailComposeController:(MFMailComposeViewController *)controller didFinishWithResult:(MFMailComposeResult)result error:(NSError *)error
{
[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

in the message i have the textfields which add to the email perfectly the only one that doesn't add in correctly is the UISwitch labeled as myswitch.

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Please refer the below code, create one NSString property initially set its text to "off" because initial state of switch is off and by using switch state change the text.**

```
    @property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *strOnOff;

      UISwitch *onoff = [[UISwitch alloc] initWithFrame: CGRectZero];
            onoff.frame = CGRectMake(0,100,100,50);
            strOnOff = @"off";
            [onoff addTarget: self action: @selector(flip:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
            // Set the desired frame location of onoff here
            [self addSubview: onoff];

-(void)gototest:(UIButton*)sender
{

    MFMailComposeViewController *mailContoller = [[MFMailComposeViewController alloc]init];
    [mailContoller setMailComposeDelegate:self];
    NSString *email = @"admin@blah.co.uk";
    NSArray *emailArray = [[NSArray alloc]initWithObjects:email, nil];
    NSString *message = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",strOnOff];
    [mailContoller setMessageBody:message isHTML:NO];
    [mailContoller setToRecipients:emailArray];
    [mailContoller setSubject:@"Feedback"];
    [delegate presentViewController:mailContoller animated:YES completion:nil];
}

        - (void)flip:(id)sender {
            if (onoff.on)
            {
                strOnOff = @"On";

            }
            else
            {
                strOnOff = @"Off";
            }
        }
```

Comment: is there anyway to make it simpler i.e. i want to the uiswitch to say on and off in a label and depending on which state its set in that label gets added into the mail composer?

Comment: @user3725924 i already added UISwitch state text into mail composer please check my code. While clicking on button that shows the MFMailComposeViewController  i added "strOnOff" in mail composer message body that is the text of UISwitch.

Answer (score 1):

You will need to create string based on UISwitch is ON/OFF and then use this string to pass in your message.

```
if ([myswitch isOn]) {
    NSLog(@"its on!");
} else {
    NSLog(@"its off!");
}
```

Comment: no in general when using just myswitch, when i add in that code nothing happens.

Comment: @user3725924 You are adding UISwitch control in NSString, because of that you are getting this error. Use my approach and add string not UISwitch to your message string.

Comment: is there anyway to make it simpler i.e. i want to the uiswitch to say on and off in a label and depending on which state its set in that label gets added into the mail composer?